# Disable Trac wiki links

Tags: trac

When using Trac it always highlights class names as a reference to a wiki page like this:

```
MyClass?
```

How could I disable this? It makes ticket text unreadable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Andrey, you can disable wiki links by adding "ignore_missing_pages" parameter to your trac config in "wiki" section.
See docs here: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracIni

Answer (score 10):

If you use "!MyClass" it should not make a link.

Comment: How could I just disable this? I don't want to add tons of "!" to my messages.

Comment: Then the solution provided by Yuri Subach would be the right way to go.

Answer (score 5):

Ideally, class names should be formatted as code, i.e. `{{{MyClass}}}`. This would also prevent the auto-linking.